# JNI shared object compatibility on different JVM versions

Tags: jvm, java-native-interface

The `GetEnv` method from JNI sdk accepts 2 parameters.

```
struct JavaVM_ {
    jint GetEnv(void **penv, jint version) {
        return functions->GetEnv(this, penv, version);
    }
};
```

Here is the possible values for 2nd parameter.

```
#define JNI_VERSION_1_1 0x00010001
#define JNI_VERSION_1_2 0x00010002
#define JNI_VERSION_1_4 0x00010004
#define JNI_VERSION_1_6 0x00010006
#define JNI_VERSION_1_8 0x00010008
```

If I indicate `JNI_VERSION_1_6` but the shared object is loaded by JVM 1.8, what will happen?
Is there a method to query JVM version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JVM is backward compatible with all previous JNI libraries.
So you should specify the *minumum required* JNI version.
`JNI_VERSION_1_4` should be OK for most cases.